# Procedural Mesh Generation Script Issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, procedural-generation

The below code shows how I'm trying to create a mesh in script that can be changed by some user defined values. I plan on using this to make voxel terrain, water, etc. However until I can figure out why this is not working (no errors are showing in Unity), I am at an impasse.

```
using UnityEngine
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof (MeshFilter))]

public class ProceduralMeshScript : MonoBehaviour {
    //PUBLIC
    public int              meshSize = 1;
    public float            width = 1f;
    public float            height = 1f;
//PRIVATE
private MeshFilter      mF;
private Mesh            mesh;
private Vector3[]       verts;
private Vector2[]       vertsUV;
private int[]           triAs;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    mF = GetComponent<MeshFilter> ();
    mesh = new Mesh ();
    mF.mesh = mesh;
    mesh.name = "CustomPlane";

    //Create Mesh Resources
    CreateVerts ();
    CreateTrias ();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void CreateVerts(){
    //Set verts[] size = equal to the needed number of verts (2 times the x and y of how ever many squares there will be <meshSize>)
    verts = new Vector3[meshSize * 2 + meshSize * 2];

    //Keep track of current vert
    int curVert = 0;

    //Create Verts based on the specifed meshSize
    for(int x = 0; x < meshSize * 2; x++) {
        for(int z = 0; z < meshSize * 2; z++){
            float xf = width;
            float zf = height;
            verts[curVert] = new Vector3(xf * x, 0, zf * z);
            curVert++;
        }
    }
    mesh.vertices = verts;
    for(int v = 0; v < verts.Length; v++){
        Debug.Log("Vert " + v + ": " + verts[v].x + ", " + verts[v].z); 
    }
}

void CreateTrias(){
    //Set triAs[] to the total number of triangle points needed (6 times how ever many squares there will be <meshSize>)
    triAs = new int[meshSize * 6];

    //Keep track of seet points
    int triPoints = 0;
    int triFocus = 0;

    //Set every triangle point
    for (int t = 0; t < triAs.Length; t++) {
        switch (triPoints){
        case 0:
            triAs[t] = triFocus + meshSize * 2;
            triPoints++;
            Debug.Log("case 0: " + triAs[t]);
            break;
        case 1:
            triAs[t] = triFocus + 1;
            triPoints++;
            Debug.Log("case 1: " + triAs[t]);
            break;
        case 2:
            triAs[t] = triFocus;
            triPoints++;
            Debug.Log("case 2: " + triAs[t]);
            break;
        case 3:
            triAs[t] = triFocus + 1;
            triPoints++;
            Debug.Log("case 3: " + triAs[t]);
            break;
        case 4:
            triAs[t] = triFocus + meshSize * 2;
            triPoints++;
            Debug.Log("case 4: " + triAs[t]);
            break;
        case 5:
            triAs[t] = triFocus + meshSize * 2 + 1;
            triPoints = 0;
            triFocus += 2;
            Debug.Log("case 5: " + triAs[t]);
            break;
        default:
            triPoints = 0;
            triFocus += 2;
            break;
        }
    }
    mesh.triangles = triAs;
 }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick note: the [unity3d] tag  is for the game engine. The [unity] tag refers to Microsoft technology with the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all fix line 1:

```
using UnityEngine;
```

Then, line 4 to create MeshRenderrer component:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter)), RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
```

Finally, insert to method "Start" code to assign Default material:

```
MeshRenderer mr = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
mr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Diffuse"));
```

**Full corrected code:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter)), RequireComponent(typeof(MeshRenderer))]
public class ProceduralMeshScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    //PUBLIC
    public int meshSize = 1;
    public float width = 1f;
    public float height = 1f;
    //PRIVATE
    private MeshFilter mF;
    private Mesh mesh;
    private Vector3[] verts;
    private Vector2[] vertsUV;
    private int[] triAs;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        mF = GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
        mesh = new Mesh();
        mF.mesh = mesh;
        mesh.name = "CustomPlane";

        //Assign default material
        MeshRenderer mr = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        mr.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Diffuse"));

        //Create Mesh Resources
        CreateVerts();
        CreateTrias();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void CreateVerts()
    {
        //Set verts[] size = equal to the needed number of verts (2 times the x and y of how ever many squares there will be <meshSize>)
        verts = new Vector3[meshSize * 2 + meshSize * 2];

        //Keep track of current vert
        int curVert = 0;

        //Create Verts based on the specifed meshSize
        for (int x = 0; x < meshSize * 2; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < meshSize * 2; z++)
            {
                float xf = width;
                float zf = height;
                verts[curVert] = new Vector3(xf * x, 0, zf * z);
                curVert++;
            }
        }
        mesh.vertices = verts;
        for (int v = 0; v < verts.Length; v++)
        {
            Debug.Log("Vert " + v + ": " + verts[v].x + ", " + verts[v].z); 
        }
    }

    void CreateTrias()
    {
        //Set triAs[] to the total number of triangle points needed (6 times how ever many squares there will be <meshSize>)
        triAs = new int[meshSize * 6];

        //Keep track of seet points
        int triPoints = 0;
        int triFocus = 0;

        //Set every triangle point
        for (int t = 0; t < triAs.Length; t++)
        {
            switch (triPoints)
            {
                case 0:
                    triAs[t] = triFocus + meshSize * 2;
                    triPoints++;
                    Debug.Log("case 0: " + triAs[t]);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    triAs[t] = triFocus + 1;
                    triPoints++;
                    Debug.Log("case 1: " + triAs[t]);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    triAs[t] = triFocus;
                    triPoints++;
                    Debug.Log("case 2: " + triAs[t]);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    triAs[t] = triFocus + 1;
                    triPoints++;
                    Debug.Log("case 3: " + triAs[t]);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    triAs[t] = triFocus + meshSize * 2;
                    triPoints++;
                    Debug.Log("case 4: " + triAs[t]);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    triAs[t] = triFocus + meshSize * 2 + 1;
                    triPoints = 0;
                    triFocus += 2;
                    Debug.Log("case 5: " + triAs[t]);
                    break;
                default:
                    triPoints = 0;
                    triFocus += 2;
                    break;
            }
        }
        mesh.triangles = triAs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Now to do some test and fix up any other problems.